# Why does my MingW-64-bit-compiled 64-bin Windows .EXE crash when adding a simple string assignment, whereas for 32-bit it works fine?

Tags: c, pointers, mingw

This code, which is part of the Open Source PuTTY terminal software, called `winstore.c`, has been working well for a number of years, compiled with MS Visual C++ 2008 and also fine with the 32-bit option within the MingW-W64 compiler.  The code contains a small modification to assign a string  `fontname="Consolas";`

When I compile it with the MingW-W64 compiler configured for 64-bit output, it is successful but it crashes immediately with a Windows APPCRASH event on execution.  I've narrowed it down to the line `fontname="Consolas";` yet it's fine for other compilers, including MingW-W64's own 32-bit configuration.

Notably `fontname` is a pointer.  Am I doing something wrong here, which is highlighted by 64-bit compilation, that doesn't happen for 32-bit?

```
FontSpec *read_setting_fontspec(void *handle, const char *name)
{
    char *settingname;
    char *fontname;
    FontSpec *ret;
    int isbold, height, charset;

    fontname = read_setting_s(handle, name);


/* Temporary change - BEGIN*/
    fontname="Consolas";
/* Temporary change - END*/    

    if (!fontname)
    return NULL;

    settingname = dupcat(name, "IsBold", NULL);
    isbold = read_setting_i(handle, settingname, -1);
    sfree(settingname);
    if (isbold == -1) {
        sfree(fontname);
        return NULL;
    }

    settingname = dupcat(name, "CharSet", NULL);
    charset = read_setting_i(handle, settingname, -1);
    sfree(settingname);
    if (charset == -1) {
        sfree(fontname);
        return NULL;
    }

    settingname = dupcat(name, "Height", NULL);
    height = read_setting_i(handle, settingname, INT_MIN);
    sfree(settingname);
    if (height == INT_MIN) {
        sfree(fontname);
        return NULL;
    }

    ret = fontspec_new(fontname, isbold, height, charset);
    sfree(fontname);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of custom functions that we don't know anything about. Have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger to figure out where in your code it really happens?

Comment: I also recommend you enable extra warnings (at least `-Wall -Wextra`)  and treat all warning messages as errors that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @user3121023 yes, but I noticed that the line above my temporary change fontname = read_setting_s(handle, name); from the original code, is modifying the string by calling a function that determines it.  Is my change any different from that?

Comment: `fontname="Consolas";` and `sfree(fontname);` Think about that for a moment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, I'm limited in so far as I'm not familiar with how to use debugging.  The way I compile the code is through cd ..\windows then MingW32-make --always-make -f makefile.mgw  There are some warnings, yes.  I'm not sure how to capture them from the screen as they zoom past fairly quickly.

Comment: As pointed out by The Dude, you are trying to free something that isn't freeable. Judging by the other (similar) lines in your code, you want something like `fontname = dupcat(name, "Consolas", NULL);` in place of `fontname="Consolas";`.

Comment: Someprogrammerdude and @AdrianMole thanks, I got it as soon as I read your comment.  To be honest I searched for information on sfree() today and could only find free() but I'm new to pointers.  Interesting that the MS VC++ and 32-bit MingW don't bother about this.

Comment: fontname = dupcat(name, "Consolas", NULL);  was not quite what I needed, because I want to force the font rather than retrieving it from a setting, but it's got me on the right track thanks @AdrianMole  The way I've done it as like this, so I free it before I modify it and make sure thereafter that I don't free it again...     sfree(fontname);
fontname = "Consolas";